# Filter EntityCollection based on a single attribute using LINQ:

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I have an entitycollection composed from a fetchXML query.

```c#
string fetch = @"
  <fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
     <entity name='new_rl'>
        <attribute name='new_rlsid' />
        <attribute name='new_productid' />
        <attribute name='new_subquantity' />
        <filter type='and'>
           <condition attribute='new_sg' operator='eq' value='" + servingGroup.Value.ToString() + @"' />
           <condition attribute='new_s' operator='eq' value='' />
           <condition attribute='new_ld' operator='eq' value='" + location + @"' />
           <condition attribute='new_productid' operator='not-null' />
        </filter>
        <link-entity name='new_ys' from='new_ysid' to='new_orderid' link-type='inner' alias='ae'>
        <filter type='and'>
           <condition attribute='new_ysid' operator='eq' value='{" + yGuid.ToString() + @"}' />
        </filter>
      </link-entity>
    </entity>
  </fetch>";


EntityCollection Labels = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));
```

I need to filter the above entitycollection based on the 'new_productid' attribute. If two entities have the same value for 'new_productid', then I only want one of those entities to be rendered into **a new filtered entity collection**. I would need new_productid and new_subquantity and new_rlsid to be in my new entitycollection.

I noticed that LINQ has the `.Distinct()` property, but all the msdn examples for CRM show how to do this with LINQ using early binding. All of my plugins are late bound and need a Linq solution for late binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows late bound with LINQ:

```
using (var context = new OrganizationServiceContext(service))
{
    var result = (from a in context.CreateQuery("account")
                    join o in context.CreateQuery("opportunity")
                    on a.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid") equals o.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_officeid")
                    where a.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value == 0
                    where o.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("parentaccountid") != Guid.Empty
                    orderby a.GetAttributeValue<string>("name")
                    select new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(a.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("accountid"), a.GetAttributeValue<string>("name")))
                    .Distinct();
}
```